# Chrome -Error Installation Failed. Google chrome installer failed to start

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, installation

I unexpectedly uninstalled or removed chrome from my netbook.

Netbook has following specifications:

- 1 gb ram
- 1.50 Ghz CPU
- windows 7 starter, service pack 1

By mistake I have removed chrome from my netbook and then when I tried to install it with internet explorer but alas! It failed and a pop-up appeared which said

> " installation failed to start. Google chrome installer was unable to
>   start"

(I don't remember what is that message exactly, it is paraphrase.)

At first , I thought that it is a virus so I scanned my Computer through various antivirus like  bitdefender,avg etc..  no virus, malware, spyware came out as result.

I was perplexed and I surfed around the net and followed the told steps like deleting registery, appdata, uninstalling or removing chrome permanently but nothing happened.

Please tell me any certain problem of my netbook with its solution or give some ways so that I can try fix my problem you can also give the ways in more detail that I have listed above like-editing registry etc.

Comment: Have you tried, to intall FireFox first, and then chrome? Before editing registry? Have you tried to download some other file with IE?

Comment: yes, i tried the mozilla firefox ..it worked but i want to use chrome as default browser.

Comment: And you have tried to install Chrome through Fire Fox ?

Comment: yes,I tried to install google chrome through firefox and IE too..

Comment: Have you tried offline instaler ? https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?standalone=1

Comment: ya..i tried chrome's alternate installer too..:( i watched many videos on youtube for the solution but nothing came as a result..now i am installing avast so that i can fix my pc issues..

Answer (score 7):

Go to Run, type "regedit" and press enter. After that delete the: `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Google","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Google","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432Node/Google"` folder.
Restart your system and now start to install Google Chrome. Now it will surely Work.

Comment: That's the perfect answer. Work like a charm. +1

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you’re receiving an installation error during Google Chrome installation process.

Let me tell you there are various causes to look after. I’ll try my best to explain each and every possibility that lead this error.

You may have to verify security permissions of Program Files (x86) and Program Files folders. Make sure administrative privileges are provided to these folders- located in system drive, usually drive C:.

1. Open Computer -> C:\
2. Right click Program Files (x86) folder, select Properties.
3. This opens up Folder Properties dialog box. Click Security tab.
4. Click Edit button, provide read/ write permissions and then click OK.
5. Do the same for “Program Files” folder in the same location.

A setup program sometimes require short file name creation. The problem arises when your Registry settings determine this feature is disabled. Modify your computer’s Registry very carefully and set NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation=0 (Remember, 0 indicates this feature will not be disabled). [Here is guide](http://chromecrashes.com/how-to-fix-windows-installer-error/) on modifying this string located in root Local Machine sub key.

Another possibility, a service named Windows Installer has been stopped. In this case, the program installation fails with an error. Restart the service using Windows Service Management tool, i.e. Services.msc

Thanks and Regards.